# How to make URL short in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

In my index.php I have a list of properties. When I click on it, it directs me to property_detail.php but with extra details on the URL making it very long and untidy. How to make it short?

[image]

Comment: Google "url rewriting"

Comment: By mapping a given set of parameters to an unique ID. You can store these information wherever you want, as long as you can retrieve it from `property_detail.php`.

Comment: You may want to look at using POST requests since this will remove the need for URL parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: @DanielWaghorn POST vs GET have different goals. You should not want to POST stuff if you don't actually want to persist data.

Answer (score 0):

Set rewrite URL rule in `.htaccess` in the root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|upload|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```